# WPF Progress bar not showing correct progress

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application where I am uploading a file in blocks. My front end is WPF and I have a progress bar to show file upload progress (upload is done by separate thread, and the progress bar is in a separate form invoked by the child thread when uploading starts).

I found the total number of blocks in the file to set the maximum property of the progress bar.

Now for each block uploaded I increment the value of progress bar by 1.

But to my surprise, the progress bar starts to increment but never completes ( it stops showing progress after few blocks ).

Here is code for the thread responsible for uploading files:

```
 System.Threading.Thread thread = new Thread(
   new ThreadStart(
         delegate()
         {
              // show progress bar - Progress is the name of window containing progress bar
              Progress win = new Progress();
              win.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
              win.Show();

              // find number of blocks
             long BlockSize = 4096;
             FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(filename);
             long FileSize = fileInf.Length;
             long NumBlocks = FileSize / BlockSize;

             //set the min and max for progress bar
             win.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                  new Action(
                     delegate()
                     {
                            win.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                            win.progressBar1.Maximum = NumBlocks;                                                        
                     }
             ), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);

             //upload file
             while (true)
             {

                      // code to upload the file

                      win.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                          new Action(
                              delegate()
                              {
                                 win.progressBar1.Value += 1;
                              }
                      ), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);

             }
       }
```

Can someone help me analyze why is this happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you expect people to debug your code without having *any* of that code?

Comment: I apologize, will keep in mind from next time, thanks

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code.  You should do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the issue:

> upload is done by separate thread, and
>   the progress bar is in a separate form
>   invoked by the child thread when
>   uploading starts

If that means your child thread *created* the form, then that's the problem. Your child thread might be updating the progress bar values, but this will just *invalidate* the display, and not necessarily refresh the display. When a control's display is *invalidated*, it simply records that it must redraw it's display the next time it gets a chance. A *refresh* is when the control actually gets to render to the screen.

A better approach is to create the progress bar form in the *main* thread.

Your worker thread can then update the status, and your main thread will refresh the display.

One thing to remember: if you're updating a control that was created in a different thread, you must do so via the control's dispatcher.

```
var dispatcher = progressBar.Dispatcher;
dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action( () => { progressBar.Value = currentProgress }));
```

---

**Edit after seeing the code**

All you need to do is move the creation of the progress variable so that it is instantiated by the main thread before the worker thread is created.

---

```
Progress win = new Progress();
win.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
win.Show();
System.Threading.Thread thread = new Thread(
   new ThreadStart(
         delegate()
         {
 // ...
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the issue of "invalidate the display, and not necessarily refresh the display.".. I didn't get that part, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, you've been a great help !! :)