# creating progressbar programmatically in wpf

Tags: wpf-controls, progress-bar

I am trying to create a progress bar programmatically in wpf. This is my code so far

```
infoWindow = new Window();
infoWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
infoWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
infoWindow.Title = "Please wait...";

StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
progressBar.Margin = new Thickness(10,0,10,10);
progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
progressBar.Height = 25;
progressBar.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
progressBar.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
progressBar.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;

stackPanel.Children.Add(progressBar);

infoWindow.Content = stackPanel;
infoWindow.Show();
```

What I get from this is a progressbar strip which is red in color. But there is no animation going on like the one that happens when we are copying files. (I don't want to show any progress, just the light which moves across the whole strip in circular fashion).
Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201519/update-wpf-progress-bar-while-filling-dataset-all-using-rx

Comment: or this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx

Comment: look at this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761474/wpf-progress-bar-not-showing-correct-progress